# iOS - Make a copy of a array object into another

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a little problem, and I need help.

I want to loop through a multidimensional array, and every time I find a value for a key ex."name" that is equal to ex. "Hello". I want to copy that array object into another array.

How do I do that?

Comment: You will probably find that Stack Overflow provides better answers if you include the code you already wrote in your question.

Comment: I agree with Adam. Without codes it is difficult to understand exact situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a 2-dimensional array and since I don't know how your objects within the array look like I take the `id` type and the method `valueForKey`:

```
 NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for(NSArray *dim1Array in yourMultidimensionalArray)
 {
    for(id obj in dim1Array)
    {
       if([[obj valueForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:@"Hello"])
       {
          [tmp addObject:dim1Array];
          break; // I assume you only want to add it once
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question but for me it seems as if the OP is asking for a copy of the object and not the array. But then again, I am unsure. Anyways, in case I got it right, only the most inner two lines would have to be changed towards `[tmp addObject:obj];`.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you would do it:

```
NSArray* newArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:oldArray]
```

Comment: -1; Morten wants to copy something only when certain values / conditions are satisfied, so your answer isn't as helpful as it should be.

Comment: As simple as that! +1