# How to copy particular array objects from one array to another array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have one NSMutableArray with two fields: name and number. The Name of Array is "Urgency" and it contains :

```
urgency: "ADMIT",
urgencyId: 5
```

My question is how can I add only the urgency into the temp array? I dont want to add the urgencyID.

Comment: is it nsmutablearray or nsmutabledictionary?

Comment: You haven't really explained your problem or your data structure very clearly. Post the code you have so far, it might speak for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [copy NSArray inside an empty NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344563/copy-nsarray-inside-an-empty-nsarray)

Comment: Hi Firdos it is nsmutableaarry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an `NSDictionary` or your array contains objects of dictionary with two keys called `urgency` and `urgencyId`.

You can get it by `[... valueForKey:@"urgency"]`

**EDIT:**

I think this (I tried to replicate what you are saying ) may come helpful for you:

```
NSString *keyUrgency = @"urgency";
NSString *keyUrgencyId = @"urgencyId";

NSDictionary *u1 = @{keyUrgency: @"u1_urgency",
                     keyUrgencyId: @"u1 id"};

NSDictionary *u2 = @{keyUrgency: @"u2_urgency",
                     keyUrgencyId: @"u2 id"};

NSDictionary *u3 = @{keyUrgency: @"u3_urgency",
                     keyUrgencyId: @"u3 id"};

NSArray *array = @[u1, u2, u3];

NSLog(@"array : %@",array);

//you want only urgencies in array
NSArray *urgencies = [array valueForKey:keyUrgency];
NSLog(@"urgencies : %@",urgencies);
```

Comment: but how can i get all the "urgency " only there 20 urgency's ?

Comment: this will return array.

Comment: Hi Anoop can please write exactly into the code format i did same but not get success

Comment: as bhargavi answers say.

Comment: Thats right Anoop but all my values are all ready stored into one nsmutable array in that array these two things are there out of that i need only "urgency" into the other string array

Comment: plz share your array....so that I can try.

Comment: self.objUrgencyVO.arrUrgency this is my array having the values urgency and urgencyID ok ..... and i wand to add the only the urgency into the following dict ...

Comment: NSDictionary *dictDataObj = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arrTitles, arrUrgency, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:TAG_TITLES, TAG_DATASOURCE, nil]];

Comment: @KuldeepRajput: check my edit, and confirm if you wanted same thing..

Answer (score 0):

You can hold all values like this in one array.

```
NSArray *allUrgency = [dict valueForKeyPath:@"urgency"];
```

Comment: If the array contains NSDictionary the result for [dict valueForKeyPath:@"urgency"]; it's NSString not NSArray.

Comment: `valueForKeyPath:`returns `id` not the `NSString`

Comment: Yes, I agree but for the scenario above urgency: "ADMIT" it's string.

Comment: Hi Bhargavi thanx for reply ,But how can i get all the urgency and what is the "dict"?

Comment: KeyPath must have a dot in between isnt'it, like `@"key.urgency`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like follow and that is from : [iOS - Make a copy of a array object into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025394/ios-make-a-copy-of-a-array-object-into-another)

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 for(NSArray *dim1Array in yourMultidimensionalArray)
 {
    for(id obj in dim1Array)
    {
       if([obj valueForKey:@"urgency"])
       {
          [tmp addObject:dim1Array];
          break; // I assume you only want to add it once
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Application is crash :(

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Urgency countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance